# Call server side C++ from webpage

Tags: javascript, c++, html

I would like to use node.js/express and socket.io to retrieve data off of a piece of hardware through a web browser, but I really dont know where to start. I currently have express serving a webpage. I would like to retrieve and display raw data in realtime (graph form) from a sensor, for this reason, socket.io looked promising. I would also need to use some server side code (c, c++?) to do some processing on this data and display the results on the page. Is Ajax the best way to do this?

I do not really have much experience with this sort of thing, so is this the best way to go about this? Better options?

Comment: AJAX? If you're using socket.io, AJAX is pretty irrelevant. Socket.io gives you your real-time communication from server to browser and vice versa over web sockets, you don't need a second client-initiated transport mechanism in the form of AJAX. Regardless, this is too open-ended for Stack Overflow. Pick one part of this question (like talking to your sensor via C++), and try to write a solution. Ask questions about it if you get stuck.

Comment: I would love to do that, my problem is that I dont know where I need to start. How about calling a C++ function that resides on the server and receiving a response that is displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can use web sockets and this c++ library. http://libwebsockets.org

and there is pretty example of its usage. http://martinsikora.com/libwebsockets-simple-http-server

Comment: (not really fully understanding all the different aspects of doing this yet) the library that is used to communicate with serverside code (c, c++, python, javascript, perl...) is determined by the language of the code you want to communicate with. Correct? and, if this is the case, can more than 1 of these websocket libraries be used at the same time? like socket.io and libwebsockets to communicate with different pieces of code.

Comment: you have no server side actually. libwebsockets provides you one. your client side code doesn't depent on server. it is just javascript( and some js libs)

Comment: also you can use Apache server and PHP instead of c++ if you like.

Comment: I was talking about the other code that libwebsockets would need to call that also resides on the server. I wasnt talking about client side at all.